# Not works fs.readFile in node js

Tags: node.js, file, fs

I have:

```
 fs.readFile('../services/Prescipcion.xml', "utf8", function (err, data) {
    console.log("err->", err);
    console.log("data", data);
 });
```

And it logs:

```
err-> { 
  [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../services/Prescipcion.xml']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '../services/Prescipcion.xml' 
}
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Do you have the file in that location? If you are *NIX, then try `ls ../services/Prescipcion.xml`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It worked for me

```
  var fs = require("fs");

    const readFIle = path => {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + path, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.stack);
          return;
        }
        console.log(data.toString());
      });
      console.log("Program Ended");
    };
```

usage:

> readFIle("/input.txt");

Answer (score 69):

The error message says `no such file or directory`, so at first sight this most likely means the path to the file is incorrect.

Either the filename is incorrect (typo?) or the directory is incorrectly resolved. Take note that a relative path will be resolved against `process.cwd()`:

> `process.cwd()`: Returns the current working directory of the process.

You can try using `console.log(process.cwd())` to help you debug the issue.

If the file `Prescipcion.xml` should be retrieved locally from where the script is run, you can also use the following construct:

`fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../services') + '/Prescipcion.xml', 'utf8');`

> `__dirname`: The name of the directory that the currently executing
>   script resides in.

Comment: `Take note that a relative path will be resolved against process.cwd()` was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

A full example that worked for me, based on other answer

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, '../rooms') + '/rooms.txt', 'utf8');
let data = ''
readStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When passing data over from a Web App to an Express server, the fs root resides under the Web App directory and NOT the server's root directory.  Therefore, the first writeFile parameter must point to a directory outside the server directory, or link over to the server file tree.

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative or absolute path as `fs.readFile` argument , but the point is that i got stumped with this was:

if you have `let path = 'c:\a\b\c.d` and you want to use it as an arg for `fs.readFile(path, {'utf-8'}, (err, content) => {//...your stuffs})` you should take care that **`\` is an escape character in js**, so `fs` read your path as `c:abc.d` then it will use this path as a relative path so `fs` will search for `C:\Users\dir_to_your_project\c:abc.d` which is obviously not a valid path and it results in a `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory...` error

so how to fix this issue?

it's very simple you should just replace `\` with `\\` in your desired path before using it as an arg in `fs.readFile()`:

```
new_path_for_fsReadFileArg = path.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also a newbie and this `path.join()` is giving me a headache but when I hard code the directory directly it works